# Cannot access attribute real value in Angular Directive template function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been looking for a time now and could not find any question/issue related to this, so I'm going to ask here if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

I am creating a directive for a  tag (I want the number to be dynamic and with angular there is no way on doing something like  so I've created a directive with a template as a function as follows:

```
angular.module("myModule").directive("myHeader", ["translateFilter", function (translateFilter) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: true,
        template: function(element, attrs) {
            var html = "", title = translateFilter(attrs.title);
            console.log(attrs); //Here i can see that attrs.size is "3"
            console.log(attrs.size); // I get {{hsize}} instead
            html += "<h" + attrs.size + ">";
                html += "<a href=" + attrs.url + " title=" + title + ">";
                    html += "<i class='fa fa-" + attrs.icon + "'></i>";
                    html += title;
                html += "</a>";
            html += "</h" + attrs.size + ">";

            return html;
        }
    };
}]);
```

And i'm using this directive inside another directive as follows:

```
<my-header url="{{url}}" icon="{{icon}}" title="{{title}}" size="{{hsize}}"></my-header>
```

Where {{hsize}} is "3".

Anyone could point me out why am i getting {{hsize}} when i do `console.log(attrs.size);` but when i do `console.log(attrs);` I can clearly see that its value is `"3"`?

In my directive I have already tried all possible combinations for the `scope` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal because {{hsize}} it's not "interpolate" by AngularJS. You can see 3 in console (when console.log(attrs)) because in the meantime Angular "interpolate" data.
For see, try to write this in your template function :

```
attrs.$observe('size', function(value){
     console.log(value);
});
```

But, if I may . It's not very nice to do it in a template function. The link functions and compile function are there to modify a template.

Look at documentation of these functions : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

And for more information on data "interpolation", look at : https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750

Comment: Before your comment, I have moved my entire code to the link function, and at the end i've done element.html(html) and it worked like a charme, meaning you have the correct answer here.